# Cambio de horario no respeta la zona horaria

Tags: oracle, weblogic

¿Qué puedo hacer si con el cambio de horario no me respeta la zona horaria? Sigue adelantada una hora; lo raro es que cuando se guarda en la base de datos toma la hora correcta.

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Provee más contexto para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola user325244, bienvenido, pregunta tonta, donde está la base de datos y donde está tu programa (ubicación geográfica), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.